# Browsing an URL with an ID (#) and bind it to a jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, hash

I've got a slideDown effect when clicking a thumbnail. This Thumbnail has an anchor with an ID:

```
<a href="#someID">
  <div class="picture">
    <img src="image.png" />
  </div>  
</a>
```

When I click on ".picture" some stuff happens (jQuery stuff with Accordion effects), the content of the box underneath the picture gets visible.

Now I have a search form. The search results have a link to these URLs with anchors, which in this case is something like **http://www.mysite.com/#someID**. When browsing this URL, my box, however, won't have the effects like when I click on it, of course.

How can I bind my (slidedown and other jQuery) events when I browse to the direct URL with its #ID without clicking on my trigger?

**I tried something like this, but it wouldn't work (maybe I just did an mistake?):**

```
if(window.location.hash) {
  // some code
} else {
  // some code
}
```

**My normal click event is this:**

```
if ( $(contents).is(":hidden") ) {
        // do stuff here
    } else {
        // do stuff there
    }
});
```

**Thank u so much in advance! :)**

Comment: show us ur full click event pls..

Comment: You could fire a click event on page load when you detect the hash. 
$(".picture").click();  
But I would need a bit more info to give a full answer.

Comment: Your first snippet would work if done properly. What did you try that didn't work?